# Nested 'for' and 'if-else' statement jinja2 template

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, jinja2

I am trying to write a nested loop in jinja2, but the last line is not printing as I expect:

```
{% for n in range(5) %}
 {% if n > 4 %}
  switchport mode trunk
 {% else %}
  interface GigabitEthernet0/{{ n+1 }}
  description {{ interface.description }}
  switchport access vlan {{ interface.vlan }}
  switchport mode access  
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of `range(5)` are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. I assume you mean `switchport mode trunk` is not being printed, which is expected - `n > 4` is never true.

Comment: When n = 5 it should print ‘switchport mode trunk’

Comment: Do you understand that `n = 5` is never true?

Comment: Thanks, I understand